# How can I push data (received from a POST route) to my frontend using Server Sent Events (Nodejs - React)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server-sent-events

the architecture I am building is the following:
[image]
I have 2 servers connected. The external server sends data asynnchronously, in JSON format. The data is posted to my server at the route `/api/webhooks/radio-events`. After that, I have the data in my controller function.

The next step is to show the data on the client side in real time. I have tried to use Server Sent Events, but I don't know how to share the data between the POST controller(which connects both servers) and the GET controller (which connects the frontend to my server)

Is this a wrong approach?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I think its better to store whaterver event the external sever sends in a database or a file, then whenever the client request this data (GET) the server responses with the data store in the database/file

Comment: Hi, maybe you are right. I'm using mongodb. Is it possible to make that in real time? I mean, when the event is stored, can I push that data in real time to the front end?

Comment: You can achieve real time update by establishing a web socket connection to your server and listing to events. So whenever external server completes an action, your server should post a trigger to the web socket which is kept alive with the front end

Comment: @FernandoHernandezRuiz yeah you can achieve that via web sockets

Comment: Thank you. Should I use the database and websocket or just sockets? Can be the websocket server in the same port than my local server?